# how to find the width of a binary number using MIPS assembly

Tags: mips

Lets say I want to calculate the the width of 9 which is `1001` in binary.

The width should come out to 4.

Another example is
`00100010100010101` the width should be 15.

The general concept is to find the MSB and LSB, preferably going from LSB to MSB and counting. Please use MIPS assembly language with no pseudo instructions.

So far:

```
#assume $1 holds 1, $2 holds the number that we want to find the width

loop:
and $3, $2, $1 #and with 1 until we find the lsb
srl $2, $2, 1 #shift right

#keep looping till we find lsb, then start counting till msb
```

Answer (score 1):

Some processors help with this, via find first one in a word, but others don't.

For unsigned numbers, since we need to look from MSB first and lower next, start with a count of 32, and go downwards.  Loop, as long as we haven't found a `1` yet, looking for high bit set (i.e. < 0 when interpreted as signed), then if not so, count -1, and shift the number left by 1.  When you find a `1`, you have the ~ log2 of the number.

If you want to do this with signed numbers, you might see if the number is positive, then do the above, otherwise negate the number and do the positive version.